# How to write a rspec for update action in view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Only User with attribute curator equal true can update homepagelist in article to true and it works fine .

```
<% if @article.homepagelist%>
    <% if current_user.curator %>
        <%= form_for @article do|f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :article_id, :value => @article.id%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :title, :value => @article.title%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :body, :value => @article.body%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :image, :value => @article.image%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :plain_body, :value => @article.plain_body %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :magazine_id, :value => @article.magazine_id%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :is_sponsored, :value => @article.is_sponsored%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :ad_title, :value => @article.ad_title %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :homepagelist, :value => false %>
            <%= f.submit "Delete from List" %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <% else %>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <% if current_user.curator %>
        <%= form_for @article do|f| %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :article_id, :value => @article.id%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :title, :value => @article.title%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :body, :value => @article.body%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :image, :value => @article.image%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :plain_body, :value => @article.plain_body %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :magazine_id, :value => @article.magazine_id%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :is_sponsored, :value => @article.is_sponsored%>
            <%= f.hidden_field :ad_title, :value => @article.ad_title %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :homepagelist, :value => true %>
            <%= f.submit "Add List" %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want to test the update action after i click on add to list or remove from list that change only the homepagelist variable in article to true when i click add to list and to false when i click on rmove from list

```
describe 'POST #update/homepagelistvariable' do
    it 'allows curator to update homepagelist' do
      @user = create(:user)
      sign_in @user
      @user.curator = true
      @article2 = create(:article)
      @article2.homepagelist = true
      patch :update, article: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:article,
                                                        homepagelist:
                                                        @article2.homepagelist)

    end
  end
```

Comment: "I want to test the update action after i click on add to list or remove from list that change only the homepagelist variable in article to true when i click add to list and to false when i click on rmove from list." Please write this as a bulleted list.  It will help you understand the assertion(s) you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

```
  describe 'PUT #update/homepagelist' do
    it 'curator can add article to homepagelist' do
      @user = create(:user, :curator => true)
      sign_in @user
      @article = create(:article, :user_id  => @user.id)
      put :update, id: @article.id,
                   article: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:article,
                                                       homepagelist:
                                                      'true')
      @article.reload
      expect(assigns(:article).homepagelist).to match(true)
    end
  end
  it 'curator can remove article to homepagelist' do
    @user = create(:user, :curator => true)
    sign_in @user
    @article = create(:article, :user_id  => @user.id,
                     :homepagelist => true )
    put :update, id: @article.id,
                 article: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:article,
                                                     homepagelist:
                                                    'false')
    @article.reload
    expect(assigns(:article).homepagelist).to match(false)
  end
end
```